# How to optimize this code, excel hangs for a second or two what to do?

Tags: vba, excel

Excel workbook hangs for a second or two when I run this code...
What to do?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim Number_of_Sims As Integer

    Number_of_Sims = 76

    For i = 3 To Number_of_Sims
        If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'don't run unless change in column A

        Application.EnableEvents = False 'stop executing this code until we are done

        If Len(Range("s10").Value) = 0 Then
            a = Cells(i, 23).Value
            Cells(9, 19).Value = a

            b = Cells(16, 19).Value
            Cells(i, 24).Value = b
        End If
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could try to move the first `Application.EnableEvents = False` out of the for loop. Add it below `Number_of_Sims = 76`.

Comment: You should also move `If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
` out of the for loop. Add this directly under `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.

Comment: what's the point of the variable a?  does it drive a calculation in b?  Depending on that answer, you may be able to get rid of that loop all together and use a formula, but without the context of a and b, it's hard to give better advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to free the loop of the things that don't depend of the loop like :

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

And then your `a` and `b` seems to be useless, so I just gathered the 2 lines!

So give this a try, that should be more efficient :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'don't run unless change in column A

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False 'stop executing this code until we are done
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    '.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim Number_of_Sims As Integer

Number_of_Sims = 76

If Len(Range("s10").Value) <> 0 Then
Else    
    For i = 3 To Number_of_Sims
        Cells(9, 19).Value = Cells(i, 23).Value
        Cells(i, 24).Value = Cells(16, 19).Value
    Next i
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: couldn't the `If Len(Range("s10").Value) <> 0` line be moved to the first line as well where the exit sub is, because nothing ever happens if that range  = 0?

Comment: Further to @ScottHoltzman's observation, why is the value in `Cells(9, 19)` being written 74 times? Just write it once as `Cells(9, 19) = Cells(76, 23).Value`. The other part of the loop can be `Cells(3, 24).Resize(74, 1) = Cells(16, 19).Value`.

Comment: Unless of course, the idea of changing one values triggers a recalculation of a formula that affects the second value. In that case, setting calculation to `xlCalculationManual` is not a good idea.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : Thx for the input, I didn't saw that before!

Comment: @Jeeped : Indeed, the resize will be cleaner if that isn't triggering anything. But for that we will need some more details from the OP...

Comment: @MFaizanFarooq : Ok, that is an unhelpful comment. **We don't even understand what you are trying to do, so please give clear and detailed explanations. If you don't, we can't help you more than this.**